# Google Place API - Autocomplete to return Precise/ Physical address

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Question: Is there a way for autocomplete API return results only for Precise locations?

Background:
We are using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete with type parameter as "address" in our application to retrieve the place ID to get the place details and have subsequent call to validate the postal code against our database and persist the address detail with postal code. What we are seeing is autocomplete shows result of street address sometimes and place ID associated with it does not have postal code. This results in failure because postal code is required for us to persist. Is there a way to restrict the autocomplete API to return only place IDs that would have postal codes?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are doing that doesn't work. Also see [constraining autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#constraining-autocomplete).  Sounds like you want to restrict the autocomplete to [types; address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.types): [supported types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.